# Password reset email html

Tags: php, html, email, passwords

I want to send an email to the user when he/she forgets their password. This email should have the link to a page where the user can enter their new password. What link do I send them? I mean should I put the username as a parameter in the url and if so how can I hide the parameters from displaying in the url. I know there are other questions that have answers for this but I couldn't really understand them. I am new to programming. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  If you have to ask this question, you will end up creating an insecure system.

Comment: In short, do not re-invent the wheel.  Use an existing, proven, login system.

Comment: Use an existing functionality for that (every framework has one). If you try to reinvent security on your own you'll just be handing your users' passwords to every script kiddie in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this using random generated string, let say 32 characters long, it is generated and saved in database, in users table, where I have a column called NotAproved. Then I send an e-mail to the user with link in witch a 32 chars string is as the parameter. The engine under the link takes the string, searches the database for the same and resets password, sets NotAproved to 0. I use same field as permission indicator if the e-mails has been confirmed when user have just registered.

Answer (score 1):

When the user requests a new password you create a unique string that you stick in the database. You then email the user a url containing that string and a path where to change the password. Finally you just have to make sure these two random strings are equal when the user accesses that URL.

But don't re-invent the wheel. Use some third part app for it. Surely your framework has at least one.

Answer (score 0):

As others already suggested, it's best to generate a random code, that is not related to any information of the user. This code can then be stored in a separate table in the database together with the userid, but here comes the important point: **Only store a hash** of this code.

If you store the code plaintext in the database, then your password-reset system will be weaker than the login formular. Often it is indeed easier to hack the password-reset function, instead of the login system.

It is a good idea to use the source code of a well known framework. If you are looking for a standalone class, that can provide such reset links, maybe you want to have a look at my [example](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset).